# Performance of Android 2.2 vs. earlier versions

Tags: performance, 2.2-froyo

One reason that I haven't switched to Android in the past is that it has seemed sluggish when I've tried phones that run it.  I see that Google claims [performance improvements](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.2-highlights.html) of 4x to 5x over previous versions, but those numbers are based on benchmarks, not on real-world use.

Does anyone have any information about how Android 2.2 affects typical smartphone usage.  Not just making calls -- scrolling through a long contact list, reading emails, browsing the web, navigating photo albums, playing games?  Ideally, a side-by-side comparison of device *X* running 2.2 and an earlier version.

Comment: This isn't a real question that can be answered; it's a request for Android performance anecdotes. Vote to close.

Comment: @Evan and others: point taken, edited to narrow the subjectivity gap.

Comment: This question is easily answered with a proper review that compares the Nexus One running 2.1 and Froyo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This page](http://johnhaller.com/jh/useful_stuff/nexus_one_outperforms_iphone_4/) has a couple of benchmarks that compare not only a Nexus One running 2.2 vs. one running 2.1, but also includes iPhones and the iPad. In both cases, the Nexus One running 2.2 outperforms the 2.1 version by over 2x.

Comment: Excellent.  Just the kind of information I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

*Google claims performance improvements of 4x to 5x over previous versions*

No they didn't claim such, what they claimed is that JIT compiler can give 4x to 5x improvement on compute-bound process (CPU-bound process; processes doing heavy computations). If you're scrolling on a long contact list, browsing web or gallery, etc you're more likely to be I/O bound by slow network or slow disk rather than CPU-bound, and JIT only helps very little in those cases.

Outside of benchmarks and games, it is in fact very rare for applications to be CPU-bound.